# Random in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want to randomize where a certain shape appears with the condition of it being anywhere along `500` on the `y` axis in `pygame`. How do I do this?

I imported `random` module but I did not know where to go from there.

This is what I want to randomize along the `500` on the `y` axis when it displays, but both shapes have to be in the same alignment.

```py
pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, ORANGE, (110, 500, 70, 45))
pygame.draw.arc(screen, GREEN, (140,485, 10, 30), math.pi / 2 , 3*math.pi/2, 5)
```

I don't want to randomize one shape to the left and one to the right, they both need to be in the same positioning but in a different place.

Comment: use python random with desired ranges, assign it to variable, use this variable for same alignment in draw arc and eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Use the Python ["random" module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) to generate the Y-position.  It looks like the ellipse and arc shapes need to maintain a constant -15 pixels difference in the `Y` co-ordinate.  So this can be stored as a constant in the code, rather than as some nameless difference in a calculation.

```
import random

ARC_OFFSET = -15

...

y_pos = random.randint( 0, 500 )
pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, ORANGE, (110, y_pos, 70, 45))
pygame.draw.arc(screen, GREEN, (140, y_pos + ARC_OFFSET, 10, 30), math.pi / 2 , 3*math.pi/2, 5)
```

There also seems to be a constant `X` offset too.  It may be best to write a function to draw this compound shape

```
import random

...

def drawShape( screen, x_pos, y_pos ):
    ARC_OFFSET_X = 30
    ARC_OFFSET_Y = -15

    pygame.draw.ellipse( screen, ORANGE, ( x_pos, y_pos, 70, 45 ) )

    arc_x = x_pos + ARC_OFFSET_X
    arc_y = y_pos + ARC_OFFSET_Y
    pygame.draw.arc( screen, GREEN, ( arc_x, arc_y, 10, 30 ), math.pi/2 , 3*math.pi/2, 5 )

...

y_pos = random.randint( 0, 500 )
drawShape( screen, 110, y_pos )
```